# Handle background push notification on iOS side of Flutter's Firebase Messaging

Tags: swift, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-ios

Until the moment of writing the FCM Flutter plugin did not implement a background handling for push notifications on iOS.
I'm trying to implement using native code(Swift) but I'm facing some difficulties.

This is my AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {


override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }
    
    let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
    let _platformChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "br.uff.uffmobileplus/uffmobile_channel",
                                                binaryMessenger: controller as! FlutterBinaryMessenger)
    _platformChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
          //omitted code
    })
    
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}


override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        let notificationChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "br.uff.uffmobileplus/notification_channel", binaryMessenger: controller as! FlutterBinaryMessenger)
    
        notificationChannel.invokeMethod("saveToDataBase", arguments: userInfo)
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    
}

}
```

(I omitted some non relevant code)

I saw some native iOS implementations and they did something near this.I'm not a Swift programmer so don't know at all if this is correct.
What is happening is that the

> didReceiveRemoteNotification

is not being called when a remote data or notification message arrives.

I'm using the platform_channel to communicate between dart and swift code.

This is the json data message:

> ```
>   "\"data\": {"
> ```

```
    "\"body\": \"$body\","
    "\"title\": \"$title\","
    "\"route\": \"$route\","
    "\"sender\": \"$sender\","
    "\"click_action\": \"FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK\","
    "\"mutable_content\": true,"      
    "\"content_available\": true"     
    "}, "
    "\"priority\": \"high\","
    "\"to\": "
    "\"/topics/$group\""
```

Yes it's written weirdly but works because it's triggering the onMessage with correct information.

**What I want is to do a background work (save on my local DB) when the data message arrives.**

Comment: did you ever get this working?